# How to get the intellisense in visual studio 2012 for AngularJS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, angularjs, visual-studio-2012, msdn

How can i get the intellisense in visual studio 2012 for angularjs in Html. I search these through many websites but it's not working ... please help

Comment: Take a look at this article [vs plugin for angular](http://madskristensen.net/post/angularjs-intellisense-in-visual-studio-2012) works perfectly

Comment: Also right click on Scripts folder in your solution and select Create _references.js

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to below Website its really works:
http://madskristensen.net/post/angularjs-intellisense-in-visual-studio-2012